# at command not working for me

Tags: bash, binutils

I am trying to test the `at` command with the following:

```
echo 'touch hi' | at now + 1 minute
```

I receive back a job id and time : `job 7 at Wed Sep 11 01:35:00 2013`.

But when I `ls` after the time has passed, I don't see the new file `hi`.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, is your `atd` running, the daemon that is responsible for running scheduled jobs?

Is the job still showing up in your queue via `atq`?

Have you received an **error email** (at is supposed to send you a local email with the output of your job, which may include error information)?

<strike>Plus, notice that the jobs **are run in the default environment of your user**, which usually means in your home directory, *not in the current directory*.</strike>

I have found it to be *occasionally unreliable* to assume that your whole environment is properly retained, including the current working directory. If you want to play safe, **try using absolute path names**, and make sure your script works with the default POSIX shell.

In my experiment just now, the `hi` file *was* created in the current directory, so it actually worked as expected for me (including environment and `$PWD`).

Comment: That last bit isn't right, at least for Linux. From the man page: The working directory, the environment (except for the variables BASH_VERSINFO,
       DISPLAY, EUID, GROUPS, SHELLOPTS, TERM, UID, and _) and the umask are retained from the time of invocation.

Comment: It's still worth using a fully qualified absolute path for the file, rather than a relative one.

Comment: @paxdiablo you are right, that's what my documentation also says. Yet, I have found this to be not too reliable then, and I've made it a habit to assume that nothing is retained.
(In a test just now, it *worked* for me, actually)